# Empty BulletSpan issue in android Edittext

Tags: android

I'm implementing a rich text editor. In that, when user clicks on bullet icon in toolbar, an empty bullet should be created with no character in it. But I can not achieve this by setting span on the cursor position. I have to add an unwanted space to do this. Using below code,

```
editable.insert(cursorPos, " ");
editable.setSpan(new BulletSpan(), cursorPos, cursorPos + 1,Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

I have also tried with LeadingMarginSpan but same result. I am getting the required feature, if the cursor is placed in first position of EditText or there is any text in that line. Also same problem persists in Numbered list also.
And the problem persists only for first bullet/Number in list. In subsequent bullet or numbered list item the span is working properly.

Can you please anyone help me how to implement empty bulletspan without any space or character ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: use setText("\u2022 Bullet"); to add the bullet programmatically. 0x2022 = 8226

Comment: Actually I have to use Numbered list also in which I am using LeadingMarginSpan, bulletspan actually extends this class. So if I can not use the span property, then it will be a mess of a coding. And also I will face problems when I want to delete any list item, especially in case of Numbered list. I also edited my question.

Comment: I know it's years later, but have you ever found a solution to this? It's bugging me as well for a while now.

Comment: I guess we'll never know